# Unwanted extra new row in CSV when reading data

Tags: c#, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to read data from an excel spreadsheet and put it in a csv file. I am using the ToCSV() extension(https://extensionmethod.net/csharp/list-string/datareader-to-csv). To remove any newline characters I added the removal of "\n" to get rid of all extra newline characters but this only fixed the issue for 90% of the data. Is there anything else I should be removing from the original strings to make sure there are no extra rows?

```
public static List<string> ToCSV(this IDataReader dataReader, bool includeHeaderAsFirstRow, string separator)
        {
            List<string> csvRows = new List<string>();
            StringBuilder sb = null;

            if (includeHeaderAsFirstRow)
            {
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int index = 0; index < dataReader.FieldCount; index++)
                {
                    if (dataReader.GetName(index) != null)
                        sb.Append(dataReader.GetName(index));

                    if (index < dataReader.FieldCount - 1)
                        sb.Append(separator);
                }
                csvRows.Add(sb.ToString());
            }

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int index = 0; index < dataReader.FieldCount - 1; index++)
                {
                    if (!dataReader.IsDBNull(index))
                    {
                        string value = dataReader.GetValue(index).ToString();
                        if (dataReader.GetFieldType(index) == typeof(String))
                        {
                            //if newline character is used in value, ensure each are replaced.
                            if (value.IndexOf("\n") >= 0)
                                value = value.Replace("\n", "");
                            
                            //If double quotes are used in value, ensure each are replaced but 2.
                            if (value.IndexOf("\"") >= 0)
                                value = value.Replace("\"", "\"\"");

                            //If separtor are is in value, ensure it is put in double quotes.
                            if (value.IndexOf(separator) >= 0)
                                value = "\"" + value + "\"";

                            if (value.IndexOf("CR LF") >= 0)
                                value = value.Replace("CR LF", "");

                            if (value.IndexOf("LF") >= 0)
                                value = value.Replace("LF", "");

                        }
                        sb.Append(value);
                    }

                    if (index < dataReader.FieldCount - 1)
                        sb.Append(separator);
                }

                if (!dataReader.IsDBNull(dataReader.FieldCount - 1))
                    sb.Append(dataReader.GetValue(dataReader.FieldCount - 1).ToString().Replace(separator, " "));

                csvRows.Add(sb.ToString());
            }
            dataReader.Close();
            sb = null;
            return csvRows;
        }
    }
```

Comment: There are *far* easier and better ways to write a CSV file. Searching for the letters `C`,`R` or `L`,`F` won't replace newlines. It will mange any data that contains those letters. You should probably use a ready-made library like CsvHelper for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replacing \r and \n with empty string would take care of eliminating newlines. However, I see you have replaced "CR LF" and "LF" with empty strings. This would actually replace any text with "LF" or "CR LF" in it and not the special characters (Carriage Return and Line Feed).

Comment: Also, you don't need to check the IndexOf things before replacing them. You can simply call replace and it would replace the string if it exists in the text else, the call will have no effect. Checking the index before replacing would be a wasteful operation.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I implemented all your changes but I am still running into the same issue. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Please share the new code for the function. Also, are these unwanted newlines appearing at the end of the csv file or in between. If it is at the end of the file, chances are that your input excel file has empty rows at the end.

Answer (score 0):

As LearnerMantis said, you are replacing actual "CR" and "LF" strings and not the special characters.

If your program is reading files coming from the same environment, you can use the `System.Environment.NewLine` constant.

The inner code of your loop would become:

```
string value = dataReader.GetValue(index).ToString();
if (dataReader.GetFieldType(index) == typeof(String))
{
    value = value.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
}
sb.Append(value);
```

If you want to manage files from different environment, then you can use the `Replace` function directly like this:

```
string replaceWith = "";
string value = dataReader.GetValue(index).ToString();
if (dataReader.GetFieldType(index) == typeof(String))
{
    value = value.Replace("\r\n", replaceWith).Replace("\n", replaceWith).Replace("\r", replaceWith);
}
sb.Append(value);
```

You could also use `Regex.Replace` if you prefer:

```
value = Regex.Replace(value, @"\r\n?|\n", "");
```